# JUnit tests pass but fail when running with Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have a test that passes when running in JUnit, but it fails on my machine and in our CI system when running with Maven. What is more interesting is that it passes on another colleagues machine who is using Windows.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this might be happening?
So to summarize:

MacOS Mojave

- Java Version: 1.8.0_131
- Maven Version: 3.6.0
- JUnit test execution: Passes
- Maven test execution: **Fails**

---

Windows 10

- Java Version: A bit different (don't have exact number)
- Maven Version: 3.6.0
- JUnit test execution: Passes
- Maven test execution: **Passes**

---

CI (Travis)

- Linux
- Java Version: **1.8.0_151**
- Maven Version: 3.6.0
- JUnit test execution: NA
- Maven test execution: **Fails**

---

Error Log from CI

```
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.saucelabs.common.JavaScriptInvokerTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.295 sec
Running com.saucelabs.common.SauceHelperTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec
Running com.saucelabs.common.SauceHelperAcceptanceTest
Mar 29, 2019 9:14:20 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Mar 29, 2019 9:14:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 19.581 sec <<< FAILURE!
shouldSetTestStatusToPassed(com.saucelabs.common.SauceHelperAcceptanceTest)  Time elapsed: 7.969 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<true> but was:<false>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at com.saucelabs.common.SauceHelperAcceptanceTest.shouldSetTestStatusToPassed(SauceHelperAcceptanceTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Running com.saucelabs.common.JavaScriptInvokerFactoryTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.033 sec
Results :
Failed tests:   shouldSetTestStatusToPassed(com.saucelabs.common.SauceHelperAcceptanceTest): expected:<true> but was:<false>
Tests run: 10, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] sauce_java ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.003 s]
[INFO] sauce_java_common .................................. FAILURE [ 32.230 s]
[INFO] sauce_junit ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] quickstart-archetype ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] quickstart-webdriver-junit ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] quickstart-webdriver-testng ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 41.039 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-29T21:14:32Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project sauce_java_common: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/travis/build/saucelabs/sauce-java/common/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :sauce_java_common
The command "mvn test -B -V" exited with 1.
```

---

Tests

```
public class SauceHelperAcceptanceTest
{
    private String username = System.getenv("SAUCE_USERNAME");
    private String accesskey = System.getenv("SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY");
    String SAUCE_REMOTE_URL = "https://ondemand.saucelabs.com/wd/hub";
    private WebDriver driver;
    SessionId sessionId;

    @Rule
    public TestName testName = new TestName();

    @Before
    public void runBeforeEachTest() throws MalformedURLException {
        ChromeOptions caps = getChromeOptions();
        MutableCapabilities sauceOptions = getMutableCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("sauce:options", sauceOptions);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(SAUCE_REMOTE_URL), caps);
        sessionId = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId();

        driver.navigate().to("https://www.saucedemo.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSetTestStatusToPassed(){

        SauceHelper sauceHelper = new SauceHelper(driver);
        sauceHelper.setTestStatus("passed");
        driver.quit();

        String jobInfo = getSauceJobInformation();
        assertAcceptanceTestPassed(jobInfo);
    }

    private void assertAcceptanceTestPassed(String jobInfo) {
        Boolean isTestPassed = checkIfTestPassed(jobInfo);
        Assert.assertTrue(isTestPassed);
    }

    private String getSauceJobInformation() {
        SauceREST sauceRest = new SauceREST(username, accesskey, DataCenter.US);
        return sauceRest.getJobInfo(sessionId.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSetTestStatusToPassedWithSeleniumJSExecutor(){
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("sauce:job-result=passed");
        driver.quit();

        String jobInfo = getSauceJobInformation();
        assertAcceptanceTestPassed(jobInfo);
    }

    @After
    public void afterTest()
    {
        if(driver != null){
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    private MutableCapabilities getMutableCapabilities() {
        MutableCapabilities sauceOptions;
        sauceOptions = new MutableCapabilities();
        sauceOptions.setCapability("username", username);
        sauceOptions.setCapability("accessKey", accesskey);
        sauceOptions.setCapability("seleniumVersion", "3.141.59");
        sauceOptions.setCapability("name", getTestName());
        return sauceOptions;
    }

    private ChromeOptions getChromeOptions() {
        ChromeOptions caps;
        caps = new ChromeOptions();
        caps.setCapability("version", "72.0");
        caps.setCapability("platform", "Windows 10");
        caps.setExperimentalOption("w3c", true);
        return caps;
    }
    private Boolean checkIfTestPassed(String jobInfo) {
        Boolean isPassed;
        try
        {
            isPassed = JsonPath.from(jobInfo).getBoolean("passed");
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            isPassed = false;
        }
        return isPassed;
    }
    public String getTestName()
    {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + testName.getMethodName();
    }
    //TODO need a test that doesn't set the test status with JS executor, in which case "passed" should be null
}
```

Source Code: https://github.com/saucelabs/sauce-java/tree/js2

Comment: Can you provide more information on the unit test.

Comment: 'Java Version: A bit different (don't have exact number)',if everything else fails, try to run it with exact same version of java... it's unlikely but it happened to me that different versions of jdk8 were acting differently causing tests to fail

Comment: and what do you mean by junit execution? and as @LeoN already suggested, a little bit more information on the test itself. We have this issue with some default encoding chosen by the operating system - and those tests fail for some special characters on windows - Additionally intellij eg. also works some magic. package private classes can be mocked in intellij but not with a CI build.

Comment: @LeoN I added the tests and the source code link as well.

Comment: @Simon Schrottner I mean that if I right click and run in JUnit, the tests pass. Also, I added the source code to my question

Comment: In my experience this is usually a symptom of different test not being properly isolated. Meaning that one test or setup in one test class can affect the result of another test. One of the ways this can manifest itself is the the running order of the tests affects if one test fails or passes - ie. double check and see if tests are ran in the exacts same order in the different environments